# how to remove lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis

Which option should I use to remove the axis lines, except the t and x(t) axis

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you should just remove the `grid=major` and `axis line style={draw=none}` options.

Comment: Thank You, and how can I get these red marks a bit smaller?

Comment: You should generally post a compilable example, so others can be of much help. To get smaller markers, you could try  `mark size=<some length>`. More generally, have a look at the `pgfplots` manual for such questions.

Comment: Here's a link to [the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf).